# Synchronising file writes in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an in-memory node/js object which I back up to disc (I'm using JSON), currently with fs.writeFile().

If this happens frequently, how can I ensure that multiple file writes don't interleave, thus corrupting the data?  I don't see anything in docs suggesting that fs.writeFile takes exclusive access to the file.  I know I could use the synchronous version, but that rather defeats the point.

I'm still fairly new to node.js, so please forgive me if this is a silly question, or it's been answered before (I did search).

Tips or links gratefully received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in any other environment, you would have to manually sync them, only your app knows the "logic" of when it's OK to interleave etc.

In other environments, you might use locks/semaphores if it's threads you're trying to sync. In node, without knowing anything else about your application, I suppose I would choose a queue: each time you want to exclusively write something to the file, enqueue that something, and have a single "worker" that dequeues and writes.

Comment: OK, thanks for that.  I suspected as much, but I'll take a look at queues.